# jasperreports: how to include chart in xlsx (Excel) report?

Tags: charts, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

At the moment, when I export report to XLSX (MS Excel) format, there is a white void at the top of the spreadsheet preceding the data - I guess, it is supposed to be the chart :). The report is also exported as HTML, PDF and JSON, all three without any visible issue.

I'm using JasperReport "community" edition. Here are the relevant lines from my `build.gradle`:

```
implementation group: 'net.sf.jasperreports', name: 'jasperreports', version: "6.6.0"
implementation group: 'net.sf.jasperreports', name: 'jasperreports-fonts', version: '6.0.0'
```

I found a few posts suggesting to set the property `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.graphics` to `false`.

OK, did that in the report template:

```
<jasperReport ..>
   <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.graphics" value="false"/>
```

Still a white hole instead of a chart.

Is there a solution to this issue, or do I just have to live with it?

Comment: I don't know about how JasperReport Community edition configure its default values in the report, but I'm using the `.jasper` file generated using iReport designer and I've never faced this issue. Have you tried exporting report to `.xls` format ? Maybe the problem is just in the new excel format since it has support for xml and other things.

Comment: @Noblesse: yes, I've tried both .xls and .xlsx to the same effect.